# sort list of json objects in python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a JSON object array as given below:

```
"results": [
        {
        "BOX_coordinate_LefTop_X": 241,
        "BOX_coordinate_LefTop_Y": 1428,
        "BOX_coordinate_RightBottom_X": 2081,
        "BOX_coordinate_RightBottom_Y": 1738,
        "BOX_language" : "English",
        "OCR_possibility0": "Resident identity Card"
        },

        {
        "BOX_coordinate_LefTop_X": 140,
        "BOX_coordinate_LefTop_Y": 3272,
        "BOX_coordinate_RightBottom_X": 1924,
        "BOX_coordinate_RightBottom_Y": 3481,
        "BOX_language" : "English",
        "OCR_possibility0": "Name: Bhawandeep"
        },

        {
        "BOX_coordinate_LefTop_X": 537,
        "BOX_coordinate_LefTop_Y": 3489,
        "BOX_coordinate_RightBottom_X": 1951,
        "BOX_coordinate_RightBottom_Y": 3686,
        "BOX_language" : "English",
        "OCR_possibility0": "Bhawandeep"
        },

        {
        "BOX_coordinate_LefTop_X": 67,
        "BOX_coordinate_LefTop_Y": 3844,
        "BOX_coordinate_RightBottom_X": 1580,
        "BOX_coordinate_RightBottom_Y": 4091,
        "BOX_language" : "English",
        "OCR_possibility0": "Nationality: Indian"

        }
]
```

---

I want to sort this list based on the `BOX_coordinate_LefTop_Y`.

`results.sort(key='BOX_coordinate_LefTop_Y')` is not working as expected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`key` for `sort` is a function, you need to pass a lambda:

```
results.sort(key=lambda s: s['BOX_coordinate_LefTop_Y'])
```